# I have problem with putting quotes inside quotes

Tags: powershell, double-quotes, quoting, single-quotes

I am trying to make one line command in PowerShell to download music file and to execute it every 1 hour
`Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden PowerShell "Register-ScheduledTask Regedit -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute PowerShell -Argument "Start-process -WindowStyle Hidden PowerShell '(New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer C:\Windows\Jjgw.wav).PlaySync()'") -Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)) -f;(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/User/Repository/raw/master/Music.wav','C:\Windows\Music.wav')"`
But i just can't setup single/double quotes to go to the last, instead to closest quotes.
I am trying to achive something like this:
`PowerShell ""command1";"command2""`
To just execute these two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asked often. The best way is to use an [EncodedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand):

```bsh
$command = {
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute PowerShell -Argument "Start-process -WindowStyle Hidden PowerShell '(New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer C:\Windows\Jjgw.wav).PlaySync()'"
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)
    Register-ScheduledTask Regedit -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Force
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/User/Repository/raw/master/Music.wav','C:\Windows\Music.wav')
}
$encodedCommand = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command.ToString())) 
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden PowerShell -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand", $encodedCommand
```

Comment: I do it via Start-Process becouse i am executing additional 2 commands after those:
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden PowerShell "Commands";(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | rm;exit

Comment: And i can't do it with $variables becouse i can't create them in PowerShell started with Start-Process and i have problem with encoding command becouse i still need to put double quotes within double quotes

Comment: Is there some kind of third quotes or something

Comment: ? There is only one Start-Process and it's function is to create new, hidden instance of PowerShell which will execute all code in background, while the main PowerShell will close.

Comment: @Gyanbu I see. Well my answer should do exactly what you requested. Have you tried it?